# do i have to run ruby gem update even if i use bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Do i have to run ruby gem update even if i use bundler

obviously it's good practice to ensure you have the latest gems, but if im using bundler do i have to bother other than keeping bundler itself up to date via gem update?

Answer (score 2):

Bundler manages only application dependencies which specified in Gemfile. If you want to update only this gems, `bundler install` or `bundle update` is enough for you. If you want to update *all* installed gems or bundler itself - use `gem update`